# Can OpenCV VideoWriter support to write frames into RTSP?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using OpenCV with IP camera, which I can successfully read the video stream by using RTSP protocol, something like this:

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
String url = "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.10.3:554/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast";
capture.open(url);
```

But now I want in the same way create a writer with `VideoWriter` and write the frame to the output stream.

Is this possible? If yes, then how? How to create a file name for the stream and how to get the stream on the other side, the same from IP camera to OpenCV?

```
open(String filename, int fourcc, double fps, Size frameSize, boolean isColor)
```

Comment: Your IP camera is working as a server, feeding frames to clients. If you've setup another server (i.e ffserver) which accepts frames from clients, then yes; you can write frames to outgoing url with `VideoWriter`.

Comment: Thank You! Can you tell me, how the ffserver can setted up and use with OpenCV?

Comment: Don't you just want to stream the opencv capture to a video? It seems from your question you already have the majority of the blocks you need?

Comment: @GPPK Yes, but is still not work to stream out the video, I can receive the stream, but now I need to feed the stream to be sent to the other side.

Comment: I think you need to make it more clear in your question that after processing the image in OpenCV you want to send the image data back out across a new RTSP stream.

Comment: @GPPK Yes, you are right. Using OpenCV the only purpose is to process images, so I did not mention this that everyone knows what I mean by this routine.

Comment: OpenCV although can get the RSTP video stream, I think it can be able to send back stream to the client side, I tried to achieve this, but it was not working, so I cam here to ask. Because this the OpenCV process is done on a server, so the result can be sent to the client side (browser etc...)

Comment: I mentioned `ffserver` as an example, there are many tutorials available on setting up `ffserver`. Personally, I don't recommend using `ffserver`; it's very compute intensive and it's going to be dropped soon from `ffmpeg` latest versions.

Comment: @Zindarod I also saw that it will be dropped soon, so there any other approach to achieve this functionality? I am using this in LAN not WLAN, so besides ffservers what is some other better approach. Thanks in advance! I have wasted my lot of time to get an answer, but did not :(

Answer (score 6):

This is possible with GStreamer. OpenCV capture using mainly, FFmpeg, GStreamer. You can capture stream by both. For VideoWriter, you can use both as well. FFmpeg can be used just to produce video file. GStreamer can be used to stream the result outside c++ OpenCV program, by video stream.

GStreamer is available for Visual Studio 2019, and works for OpenCV 4.2. The installation is even easier on Linux.

This is easy, but a lot of room for mistakes. The GStreamer pipe works. The extended description for installation is available here [Tutorial](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2020/03/compile-opencv-4-for-visual-studio-2019.html).

[image: Gstreamer result]

I used3)

- OpenCV source opencv-4.2.0
- OpenCV source opencv_contrib-4.2.0
- Cmake 3.17 release candidate 3, This is important.
  I used development and runtime installer for MSVC GStreamer
  Gstreamer 1.16.2 runtime installer
  Gstreamer 1.16.2 development installer
  [image: what to download]
  The following steps are common for OpenCV to build from source and OpenCV installation. Additionally, these resources needs to be added during cmake configuration.
  [image: Gstreamer Cmake opencv config]

Now build OpenCV project generated by CMAKE in Visual Studio 2019. The last important thing is to set environmental variables to find GStreamer Runtime. Into system variable path: add

- xxx\1.0\x86_64\bin
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0
  [image: Environmental variables]

You need to use VideoWriter with gstreamer Pipeline.

```
VideoWriter writer( "appsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.0.116 port=8080 recover-policy=keyframe sync-method=latest-keyframe unit-format=buffers units-max=1 buffers-max=0 sync=true ",
        0,
        5,
        Size(320, 240),
        true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I have already implemented the functionality, your explanations are nice and give VOTE UP to make the answer for others to know it is helpful.